# PHP SOAP Request, remove ns1: et ns:2 from request

Tags: php, soap, namespaces, xml-namespaces, soap-client

I would like to remove ns:1 and ns:2 from my Soap request.
Actually I got this when it is generated:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="*********" xmlns:ns2="**************"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns2:shp:sc><user>***</user><password>*******</password><companyName>******</companyName><autoCommit>***</autoCommit></ns2:shp:sc></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:p_put_order><put_orderRequest><shop_order>TEST2</shop_order><shop_account>100000</shop_account><order_comment>test</order_comment></put_orderRequest></ns1:p_put_order></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Then in my php file, I got :

```
 $options = array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,
                 "encoding"     => "UTF-8",
                 "trace"        => true,
                 "exceptions"   => true,
                         'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,

                        );

    $client = new SoapClient($soapURL, $options);
    $header = new SoapHeader($soapURL,'shp:sc',$auth, false);
    $headerSoap = $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

I tried to use, SoapVar(), __doRequest() and none of those works ...
Have you got an idea about that ? 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

$header = new SoapHeader($soapURL,'shp:sc',$auth, false);

Please remove $soapURL from here. First argument is suppose to be namespace. Please see documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php . If this fail please post WSDL file.